# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification triggered two times on iOS 8 and only one time on iOS 7 when rotating

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, keyboard, nsnotification

From the very simple piece of code below, I have a strange behavior difference between iOS 7 and 8 when rotating :

- On iOS 7 the keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide are called only one time each.
- On iOS 8  the keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide are called two times each.

I have created a very simple project to ensure that it was not a side effect of my main project, but it is not.

Is it a documented behavior difference ?

Regards.
Sébastien.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will show.");
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will hide.");
}

@end
```

Comment: While this may be an internal bug, you should try not to concern yourself with the implementation of the keyboard system, as long as the notifications are logical (`show` -> `hide` -> `show` -> `hide` and not `hide` -> `show` -> `show` -> `hide`). Try to inspect the call stack to see the logic behind Apple's posting the notification.

Comment: Put `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidLoad` and try.

Comment: I agree, but my application should work on iOS 7 and iOS 8 (and 9), it's a problem to have a piece of code running correctly (when the device is rotating) with both one and two notification....

Comment: Already tested to put in viewDidLoad, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Sébastien
I think you should add keyboard notification in the viewDidLoad() and then try again, hope it will help you.

Comment: You can use cancelPreviousSelector and after that performSelector method.

Comment: You mean add in KeyboardWillShow / KeyboardWillHide methods something like :    
        
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                                selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                  object:nil];        
Same behavior.

Comment: No, whenever you want to update something in these method call it by this method as i recommended.